# How to use Cocoapods in an embedded framework and in app

Tags: ios, shared-libraries, cocoapods

I want to integrate an action extension into my app. I generated an embedded framework with the shared code between app and extension.

Now I need to access a pod in the embedded framework. How do I link the pods into the framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `target` to separate the pods for the app and your embedded framework.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

target :App do
  pod ...
  pod ...
end

target :Framework do
  pod ...
  pod ...
end
```